# History.push Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a nav bar

where I click a button and it will call another page
however i'm using function component

and me i don't know how i could get my history

I tried this:

> onClick = {() => {this.props.history.push ('/ xd')}}

and I had error:

> Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

```
export default function Navigation({props}) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar} >
          <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <Toolbar >
<Link to="/xd">
<Button className={classes.button} onClick={() => {this.props.history.push('/xd')}} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false"  color="secondary">
   Home
</Button>
</Link>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised"  disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
<Button className={classes.button} variant="raised" disableFocusRipple="false"  disableRipple="false"  centerRipple="false" color="secondary">
  Home
</Button>
        </Toolbar>
        </Container>
      </AppBar>
    );
}
```

my route app

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
    <Header/>
    <Navigation/>
    <Container maxWidth="lg" >
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route path="/xd" component={AuthPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      </Container>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't destructure props this way - I'd suggest you to simply remove curly brackets `{}` from arguments:

```
function Navigation(props) {
```

but if you really want to use destructuring:

```
function Navigation({ history })
```

Next thing - `this` is undefined in function expression - just use `{() => props.history.push('/xd')}`

You will probably have to wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC.

```
export default withRouter(Navigation);
```

Comment: hi i try this https://pastebin.com/6DfZLvLb but got  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Could you ask me one more question if it doesn't bother you?

Comment: @Felipe Go ahead

Comment: i set my router app already with my

header
navbar
footer

but on a route / login
I wish my navbar and footer header didn't appear

how do i get this?

https://pastebin.com/wxMah0Jx

Comment: @Felipe You could use `Route` for it. `<Route path=['/', '/xd'] component={Navbar} />` so Navbar will only appear in `/` and `/xd` routes and will **not** appear on `/login`

Comment: @Felipe Oh, `path={[...]}` - forgot about curly braces

Comment: i have     <div>
    <Header/>
    <Navigation/>
    <Container maxWidth="lg" >
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={LandingPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route path="/xd" component={AuthPage} exact={true} /> 
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      </Container>
    </div>

Comment: I have navigation and header

instead of declaring

    <Header />
    <Navigation />

do i need to declare as route not to appear in my / login?

Comment: @Felipe Please ask new question regarding this problem, maybe others can help, oki?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `this` in functional components try using `props.history.push('/xd')`,

And if you are using `react-router` make sure you wrap your component with `withRouter` hoc